# Making Image Slider with UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am making an app that the user can upload 1 to 3 photos.
I want the user to be able to see them it as a slider in with Page Control,
I started to code it but for some reason the images do not added to the scrollView (I see nothing when running the app).

This is my code so far:

```
    class dogProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    var imagesArray = [UIImageView()]
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image1: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image1.png"))
        let image2: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image2.png"))
        imagesArray.append(image1)
        imagesArray.append(image2)
        var countIndex = CGFloat(0)
        for image in imagesArray {
            image.frame = CGRectMake(countIndex*view.frame.width, 0, view.frame.width, 100)
            scrollView.addSubview(image)
            countIndex = countIndex + 1
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: This library might help you https://github.com/Lasithih/LIHImageSlider

Comment: This might help someone looking for an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212242/image-slider-with-uiscrollview/45216057#45216057

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line after the for loop ends

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(countIndex*view.frame.width,0)
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 175)

    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cake"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "food")]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to what you provided, you haven't added the scrollView to the view. So, first step, make sure the scrollView is added to the view. `self.view.addSubiew(scrollView)`. Change the scrollView background to make sure it is there.

Also, I don't see that you have initialized the scrollView frame. The scrollView has no frame, so it won't show anywhere. Make sure that you initialize the scrollView.

Comment: I added it from the mainstoryboard to the UIViewController

Comment: Ahh!  I see the outlet now! So what happens when you change the background of the scrollView? Can you see it change colors?

Comment: well when I change the background color it does change but it do not get added when.. (Sorry for the delay :) )